# Monotone vector field

Tags: calculus

I am new here so I will make it simple:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth vector field. $F$ is monotone if:
$$\left \langle F(x)-F(y),x-y  \right \rangle\geq 0,\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$$

I know that $F$ is locally monotone if for sufficiently close $x$ and $y$ it holds that:

$$\left \langle DF(x-y),x-y  \right \rangle\geq 0$$
where $DF$ is the derivative of $F$. Is there a general property based on the concept of derivatives that holds for any $x$ and $y$, regardless of the distance in between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am not sure what you mean by $DF(x-y)$. If this is the Jacobian at $x-y$, then this makes no sense (you cannot form the inner product).

Second, yes: What you want is that the Jacobian $DF(x)$ at every point $x$ is positive semidefinite meaning that if $A= DF(x)$, then the symmetrization of $A$, namely
$$\tfrac{1}{2}A+\tfrac{1}{2}{A^T},$$
is positive semidefinite. (Some/most authors require symmetry in their definition of positive semidefiniteness.)

For a proof, see Proposition 12.3 in the book by Rockafellar and Wets entitled *Variational Analysis*.

Comment: I meant $DF$ as the linear mapping that approximates the function. I just checked the proposition you mentioned and it is really clear. Turns out I was doing it right, but it is good to know that I was not wrong. Thanks!